# how do I get the UserID from someone who goes to the voice channel? (look)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have the code:

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID;
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID;
 
    if(newUserChannel === "781521384018542622") //don't remove ""
    { 
        // User Joins a voice channel
        console.log("Joined vc with id "+newUserChannel);
    }
    else{
        // User leaves a voice channel
        console.log("Left vc");
    }
 });
```

how do i get the ID of the person who came in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two parameters passed through the `voiceStateUpdate` are [`VoiceStates`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState): representations of a [`GuildMember's`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) voice state (thus the name).

This means that every `VoiceState` will have a [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=member) property.

From there, you have access to the entire `GuildMember` object, including their [`id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=id)

```js
// these parameters should be renamed to be more accurate
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  // ...
  console.log(newState.member.id);
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem so it's easier to find in the future by others who share your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `newMember.member` to detect the member, 
> and then use `user.id` to get userID

> example : \

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID;
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID;
  let user = newMember.member

  if(newUserChannel === "channel_id") {
    // console.log UserID
    console.log("user is is : " + user.id)
    // console.log User voice_channel
    console.log("Joined vc with id " + newUserChannel);
  }
  else {
    // User leaves a voice channel
    console.log("Left vc");
  }
});
```